# trace of special unitray group is simply connected

Tags: general-topology, matrices

This is about the sentence

> To see this, note that $SU(n+1)$ is simply connected, and thus so is its image under the continuous map $$tr:SU(n+1)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}.$$

from https://blogs.ams.org/visualinsight/2013/12/01/deltoid-rolling-inside-astroid/

Someone pointed out to me that the map needs to be injective to preserve simply connected. But the trace isn't injective. So I need some other way to show that the image of $SU(n+1)$ under the trace is simply connected.